# Meaning of: Make that leap

Tags: meaning, idioms

In the Dictator movie, Alaeddin says to his double:

> How would you even make that leap? Tamir to Dennis?

What does **make that leap** mean? I can't understand based on the meaning of **leap** in dictionaries.

Comment: Maybe you should include more of the dialogue. What are Tamir and Dennis?

Comment: The double has been confusing the name Tamir with Dennis, and Alaeddin was wondering how he was confusing these two name

Comment: That explains it, then. One may easily confuse similar sounding names, like Ari and Erin, but how do you confuse such dissimilar names as Tamir and Dennis? The difference in sound is great, and the difference can be compared to a leap.